How to share custom-set-variables settings with colleagues?
In my .emacs file, I have some settings that I need to share with my colleagues to ensure that other tools I've shared in a Git repository work correctly. I was thinking of moving these settings to a file within the same Git repository. (I'm ashamed to say, but so far we've been sharing the entire .emacs file, but this makes it much more complicated to have personalized settings.)
All we need to do then is to include in the .emacs file the instruction to load this file. So far, I don't have major doubts. However, I'm wondering what the best way is to share some configurations that are currently set by the custom-set-variables function.
For example I have:
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(load-prefer-newer t)
 '(package-selected-packages
   '(markdown-mode json-snatcher json-mode request edit-server))
 '(tex-start-options "-synctex=1 "))

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))

(package-initialize)

(package-install-selected-packages)

How can I ensure that everyone has installed the packages I deem necessary? Do I need to use set-variable to set the variables defined by custom-set-variables?

Do C-h v custom-file.

@NickD This seems not different than sharing the .emacs file. I need to share only a portion of my configuration. I need to switch from custom-set-variables to something else (setq? set-variable? custom-set-variable?).
